# Built-in prefix + notation in python

Tags: python-2.7

I've got a function that takes a binary function as an argument and does some other things using that function. Is there a built-in way to pass the infix `+` function as a prefix binary function without making a `lambda x,y: x + y`, i.e. is there some built-in function that acts like +(1,2) = 3? Same question for `-`, `*`, `/`, and `**`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it's been like a year at this point, but I stumbled across an answer. All of the infix operations are implemented like normal functions in the [operator module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html). So, for addition you can just refer to `operator.add`